# byobu-tmux initialize command option

Tags: tmux, byobu

I installed byobu(v5.60), tmux(v1.8).
Then I found a difference with an old version, byobu(v5.27)tmux(v1.7)：

The old version byobu-tmux start byobu server with command like(checked by top -c)

`tmux -2 -f /*****/share/byobu/profiles/tmuxrc new-session /*****/bin/byobu-shell`,

but the new version is

`tmux -2 -f /*****/share/byobu/profiles/tmuxrc new-session -n - /*****/bin/byobu-shell`.

So the new version will initialize a window with name "-". I don't want to use a name for windows, so I have modified the F2 bind to open noname window, but the first one is still a problem.

How to close the `-n -` option when byobu server starts?

Answer (score 0):

Naming the window "-" is unfortunately the only compromise I can find to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1215210).

Here's what you can do...  You can add one simple line your configuration that would rename each new window to the empty string.

Add this in your `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf` file:

```
bind-key -n F2 new-window \; rename-window ""
```

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: I have already added this config. The first "-" window is my problem. I think it is a build-in function, right? After compiling, the start command can't be changed anymore? The old version was compiled on a gentoo environment by a senior, so I try to ask his help. I'll add a new comment if I solve it anyway. Thanks!

Comment: The old version has default empty window name. So I read executable files of byobu. I removed `-n -` in line 111 of 'byobu', then the first window showed 'bash' as name. Next, I turned off automatic-rename function in the profile of tmux, then the first window name became 'byobu-shell'. From beginning, `shelltitle ""` was input into the */share/common file. After failing, I compared other scripts between versions. Finally, I think you changed something to fit tmux and screen respectively, but led this bug by chance. So u added the makeshift `-n -` into default, and changed the F2 bind. -->

Comment: <--Right? I suggest fixing it as possible.